# No signal showing on LCD TV when I connect a Laptop via VGA to HDMI cable

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv

I am trying to connect my laptop to a Samsung LCD TV by VGA TO HDMI cable
My Laptop finds the Samsung tv on display setting.
But when I press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> key  to switch display modes my TV displays `No Signal`

My laptop specifications are:

```
Lenovo R61 ThinkPad, Model: 8935AE7
Window7 Ultimate 32 bits
2GB RAM
VGA Port available
No HDMI Port
```

My TV specifications are:

```
Samsung LCD 26 "
HDMI Port available
VGA Port Available
```

I want to know what is the problem?

When I connect another Dell Laptop (Window7 32 bit) with HDMI to HDMI cable it works properly.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How much did your HDMI to VGA adapter cost? There are low cost (< $10)passive cables that do nothing but convert the two connectors to each other, but they require specific devices to operate - your laptop is not ready for this. A proper solution for this problem costs a lot more, it is an active converter selling around $100 cheapest...

Comment: I have also tried with VGA > VGA, it also not working.... Laptop showing "Display on external VGA  device", what to do now?

Comment: Guess it's a fault with your laptop's VGA port...

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop and TV have S-Video port then try with S-Video.

Comment: @Chirag, I already buy and tried with 2 cables, 1) VGA>VGA 2) VGA > HDMI, now do not want to buy blindly and waste my time and money...